# Dictionaries with functions

Tags: python

I'm trying to use dictionaries as switch.I've written it:

```
a = {'1': f1(x, y), '2':  f2(x)}
while True:
    try:
        selection = getOption()
        b = a[selection]

        break

    except Exception:
        print "Error"
```

but I have the following problem: I don't want to run f2 if I choose 1,but it seems that although I choose option 1,f2 runs. How can I fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In your code, creating the dictionary already executes the functions.  To prevent this, you should store references to function objects in the dictionary, not the results of the function execution.  For your particular case, you could use lambda functions:

```
a = {'1': lambda: f1(x, y), '2':  lambda: f2(x)}
selection = getOption()
b = a[selection]()
```

Note the pair of parentheses at the end of the last line to call the function object retrieved from the dictionary.

If all functions receive the same set of arguments, say `(x, y)`, you can simplify this to

```
a = {'1': f1, '2':  f2}
selection = getOption()
b = a[selection](x, y)
```

Comment: @sven I had to modify the dictionary definition to make this working. Correct me if I am missing something. `a = {'1': lambda x: func1(x), '2': lambda x,y: func2(x,y)}`

Comment: @gl051 Your version would be equivalent to `a = {'1': func1, '2': func2}` (just needlessly verbose and slower).  The problem with that is that you don't know how to call a function that you retrieved from that dictionary.  If it's the first one, you have to call it with just `x`.  If it's the second one, you need to call it with `x` and `y`.  This makes the whole pattern of using a dictionary to dispatch between several functions rather useless, since you need if statements to distinguish the cases anyway, so you can do it without the dictionary just as well.